# Two Forms two buttons asp validating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi ive two forms on one page like this

```
 <form action="#" class="account_signin">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlSignInMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label for="user_email" class="inputlabel">E-mail</label>
                            <asp:Textbox id="txtSignInEmail"  class="inputbox inputlong" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label for="user_pw" class="inputlabel">Password</label>
                             <asp:Textbox id="txtSignInPassword"  TextMode="password"  class="inputbox inputlong" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_submit">
                         <asp:Button ID="btnSignIn" Text="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="btnBlue" />

                            <br class="clear"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
  <form action="#" class="create_account">

 <div class="form_row">
                            <label for="name" class="inputlabel">Name</label>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" class="inputbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <span class="mandatory">Required</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form_row">
                            <label for="surname" class="inputlabel">Surname</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" class="inputbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <span class="mandatory">Required</span>
                        </div>
  <div class="form_submit_register">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed egestas gravida odio ac scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam pharetra mauris et nunc rhoncus tincidunt.</p>
                     <asp:Button ID="btnReg" Text="Register" runat="server" Class="btnBlue" />
                    <br class="clear"/>
                </div>
           </form>
```

But in the code behind its only firing one of the buttons, and works fine.

How do i get both firing in the code behind?

thanks

Comment: @hmqcnoesy - The OP is using VB.NET (based on the tag) which allows event handlers to be bound in code-behind. E.g. `Private Sub btnSignIn_Click(ByVal sender As...) Handles btnSignIn.Click`

Comment: Ive added an answer in C# but if you need help converting just post your code behind and Ill edit it for you

Answer (score 0):

OK Im guessing here but are you trying to register the user then sign them in automatically by trying to call the sign in event handler? If so then you need to refactor the code in the sign in method to abstract out a method and fire that from the end of the register event like this:

```
public void btnReg_OnClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // what ever your logic currently is
 SignIn();
}

public void btnSignIn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SignIn();
}

private void SignIn()
{
  // place your logic from the sign in event handler into this method.
}
```

Apologies for the C# syntax - you should be able to get the idea though from this - youll need to do this in VB.NET syntax in you're app of course!

Comment: basically on the page the user has an option to sign in or register.So in the code behind i have two event handlers                   Private Sub btnSignIn_Click(ByVal sender As...) Handles btnSignIn.Click                                         and                                                                      Private Sub btnRegister_Click(ByVal sender As...) Handles btnRegister.Click                                                         But when the register button is clicked it doesnt fire. when the sign in button is clicked  it does work. I want to get the reg button working aswell